# Hibernate mapping user relation to entities

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, entity-relationship, entities

Let's se we have Hibernate entity `User` with basic fields such as `username`, `password`, `roles` etc..

Now we have an entity such as `Car`.

`User` has a `OneToOne` relationship with `Car`, cause he can own a car. But he also has besides this a `OneToMany` relationship to `Car`, because he also owns the cars of his children. But in the frontend I want to know which cars he owns for himself and which cars he owns for his children. The same applies to the relationship between `User` and `motorbike` (his own, his childrens, etc...)

How would the `User` entity class look like? Is it good to have the relationships mapped in an "Helper" entity such as `UserData`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username")
        })
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_DATA_ID")
    private UserData userData;
```

`UserData`:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table( name = "user_data")
public class UserData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWN_CAR_ID")
    private Car ownCar;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER_CAR_ID")
    private Car partnerCar;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_children_cars",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_data_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
    private Set<Car> childrenCars = new HashSet<>();

    public boolean addToChildrenCarSet(Car c) {
        return childrenCars.add(c);
    }

    public UserData() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you ask for an opinion, I would say it gets unnecessary complicated if you use the intermediate entity user_data. :-) There is no real drawback to add more fields and keys into the user class - performance is probably also better then using the EAGER fetching. If performance is an issue, better optimize querys later on then splitting the table now.

Also the `@ManyToMany` I would avoid - better create the intermediate table and relations yourself. You can check out https://bootify.io and create your database schema there. There is no EAGER fetching and also no CascadeType.ALL (both only good ideas in special cases), you would probably add more problems with that then actual helping in any way.

So the `addToChildrenCarSet` method would end up in a `@Service` class, in a method with `@Transactional`, in my proposal.